# Rails Filter Parameters Filtering Too Much

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my filter parameters initializer, I'm filtering out all password related parameters that matter already:

```
# config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]
```

But more parameters are being filtered out than I'd expect. It looks like anything that has "password" in the name filtered from the logs.

```
 {"password_invite_form"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Is there any way to prevent pattern matching for filtered parameters and match the precise parameters that I have set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, rather than a string or symbol, if you want to explicitly control the pattern matching.

```
# config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [/^password$/, /^password_confirmation$/]
```

This will tell Rails to filter "password" and "password_confirmation" exactly, but not filter other parameters that contain "password" as a substring.

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised the documentation does not emphasize this more. It is mentioned in passing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#redirects-filtering) but does not mention that the same applies to log filtering. In an app I maintain, filters intended to hide `dln` and `tin` fields were effecting `dln_state` and `reporting` fields.

Comment: Worth noting for future visitors that you can do 'deep filtering' even with regular expressions, at least in Rails 5, but the dot separator does need escaping. e.g. in my case the filter `/attachments\.content$/` happily doesn't match the `content_type` attribute of nested attachments, nor the `content` attribute of any other model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would have to monkey patch the part of rails that's filtering out params that contain "password".

If it were my project I'd let rails continue to do its thing and just choose a different name for that parameter. If you need help with how to do that just comment.